# Spring MVC form radio input not updating model

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm creating a web application using Spring MVC framework and forms.

I'm having trouble getting my form to update the field `position` in my PlayerModel. It simply doesn't save the value when I submit the form (**check the controller inline comment on the submit() function**).

If I select either radio button (with values `1` and `2`) and submit, the model reaches the controller with value `0`.

Despite having read countless similar questions/answers here on StackOverflow, I am unable to get this to work. What am I doing wrong here?

**[EDIT]**

I figured out the problem. For some reason, the value of the `name` attribute in the radio input is being used to match with the model attribute, instead of using `path`.

```
<input type="radio" id="index1" value="1" path="position" name="index" />
```

So it is trying to match `index` with the model, which of course does not exist, instead of using the `position` value in the path attribute.
Shouldn't it be the other way around?

**playerView.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form action="/game/playerView" method="POST" modelAttribute="playerModel">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="radio" id="index1" value="1" path="position" name="index" />
                        <input type="radio" id="index2" value="2" path="position" name="index"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**GameController.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("playerModel")
public class GameController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "playerView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(ModelMap map) {
        PlayerModel playerModel = new PlayerModel();
        playerModel.setPosition(0);
        map.addAttribute("playerModel", playerModel);
        return new ModelAndView("playerView", "playerModel", playerModel);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "playerView", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submit(@ModelAttribute("playerModel") PlayerModel playerModel, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
        playerModel.getPosition(); // returns 0
        model.addAttribute("playerModel", playerModel);
        return new ModelAndView("playerView", "playerModel", playerModel);
    }
}
```

**PlayerModel.java**

```
@Resource
public class PlayerModel {
    private int position;

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason the value of the 'name' attribute in the radio input is being passed to the model instead of the 'path' attribute. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring-MVC form tag therefore please do not use this `<input type="radio" id="index1" value="1" path="position" name="index" />` insted of use like this [(For more details)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-radiobuttontag)

```
<tr>
    <td>Sex:</td>
    <td>
        Male: <form:radiobutton path="sex" value="M"/> <br/>
        Female: <form:radiobutton path="sex" value="F"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and there is no **path** variable in HTML `<input type="radio">` ,
path should be used in the spring type declaration.

eg : 
`<form:input path="firstName"/>` this code is changed to `<input name="firstName" type="text"/>` by [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag)

Comment: This is indeed the problem. I found this silly mistake shortly after posting the question edit. I was going to post my awnser, but you have already explained very clearly. Thanks